# How do I rename a VMWare virtual disk (vmdk) if all I have is VMware Workstation Player for Windows?

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I was provided a virtual machine folder and can use it without issue but now I want to make a copy with a different name.

How do I do this if all I have is VMware Workstation Player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*OK, went deep into the webs today and figure this out.*

Say you have a vm in a folder `c:\myVM` and you want to make a copy called `c:\newVM`.

Inside `c:\myVM` it looks like this.
[image]

## A. Prep newVM

1. In VMware Player (referred to as `player` going forward) run myVM and do a full shutdown using the official OS operation.
   *Start > Power > Shutdown.. if Windows 10.

   Apple > Shutdown... if MacOS.

   etc.*
2. Make a copy of the myVM folder and rename it newVM.
3. Open newVM in `player` via *Player > File > Open...* and select `Edit virtual machine settings`.
4. Select the Hard Disk device and click `Remove`.

   [image: vm hard drive setting]
5. Close `player`.

Your new vm is now ready for renaming.

## B. Rename the virtual disk

1. Go to the [VMware sdk site](https://code.vmware.com/sdks) and find the Virtual Disk Development Kit (VDDK) in the Platform and Compute section.
   [image]
2. Download the newest version of the VDDK.
   *Yes, it's painful, but you'll need to create a VMWare account to download files. Sorry.*
3. Inside the downloaded zip file copy the `bin` folder and paste it into `c:\newVM`.
4. [Open a command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) at `c:\newVM`.
5. Enter this command `vmware-vdiskmanager -n ../myVM.vmdk ../newVM.vmdk`

The virtual disk is now renamed.

## C. Update all support files with the new name.

Inside `c:\newVM`.

1. In a text editor open `myVM.vmx` and do a find and replace `myVM` with `newVM`.
2. Close and save.
3. In a text editor open `myVM.vmxf` and do a find and replace `myVM` with `newVM`.
4. Close and save.
5. Rename each of the files using `newVm`.
   It should look similar to this.
   [image: newVM folder structure]

## D. Mount the new vmdk file.

1. Open newVM in `player` via *Player > File > Open...* and select `Edit virtual machine settings`.
2. Click the Add button and select `Hard Disk` > Next button.
3. Select `SATA` > Next button.
4. Select `Use an existing virtual disk` > Next button.
5. Browse to `c:\newVM` and select `newVM.vmdk` > Open button.
6. Finish button > OK button.
7. Finally, select `Play virtual machine.`
8. You will be asked if you moved or copied the vm... select `Copied`.
   [image]

## Done!

The newly named VM should fire up and work as if nothing has changed!

Comment: Thank you kind stranger, Your detailed answer saved me a ton of trail and error. Much appreciated.